# Placeholder hides when user reset the form

Tags: html, forms

I have tried following plugins but all have same issue in Internet Explorer . I am using IE 9. When ever I click on `input type='reset'` then the placeholder disappears. Is there a way to fix this issue?

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder
http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Answer (score 0):

IE is the culprit here... Unfortunately, these browser versions are making developers life harder and it is something that we all have to deal with all the time. Anyway, to get back to your point, here is an official link to the discussion of the similar issue:
[IE10 data-placeholder-focus ignored](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js/issues/31)

Hope this helps to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that after I performed a reset on the form via JS (jquery), if I then trigger click events on each input, the placeholders would appear again...

```js
form.trigger('reset');
$('input,textarea',form).trigger('click');
```